# Is it possible to trigger an ion-select change without changing the model?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a simple `ion-select` in a dummy component:

```
    <ion-select
      [value]="objectConfig!.soundType"
      interface="popover"
      (ionChange)="newSoundType.emit($event)"
    >
      <ng-container *ngFor="let soundType of SoundTypesArray">
        <ion-select-option [value]="soundType" id="soundType-{soundType}">
          {{ soundType  }}
        </ion-select-option>
      </ng-container>
    </ion-select>





/// model:
@Input() objectConfig: ObjectConfig
```

it has just one job. Tell me when the user selected another `SoundType` (`soundTypeA`,`soundTypeB` and `soundTypeC` where `soundTypeC` requires the user to more steps or just cancel).

The problem I am having right now is that when the user chooses `soundTypeC` and cancels the `<ion-select>` box keeps showing `soundTypeC` as selected value instead of the previous one, even when `objectConfig` stills holds `soundTypeA` as `soundType` value.

I know I can resend the `input()` from my parent component but I am trying to prevent redraws. Is it possible to prevent `ion-select` to change their own value and just respect this -> `[value]="objectConfig!.soundType"` ?

**Edit:**

To clarify: `objectConfig` is holding the **correct** value. I need `ion-select` to  reflect what `objectConfig.soundType` says.

Using the banana in the box (`[()]`) with `value` or `ngModel` does not work.

**Edit2 Stackblitz:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-select-problem?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

**Edit3 Stackblitz:** 
Using [carlosGlegaspi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59574394/1255819) the external showed value of the ion-select is the correct but internally `ion-select` still holds the changed value

[image]

Comment: Can't you use ngModel instead of value attribute?

Comment: @Chellappanவ no, the behavior is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [carlosGlegaspi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59574394/1255819) as base I managed to fix this although it feels like a hack.

instead of send directly an event I call a function first and I also send a reference to `ion-select`:

```
 <ion-label>Sound Type</ion-label>
            <ion-select
          #ionSelect
      [ngModel]="configObject.soundType"
      [selectedText]="configObject.soundType"
      interface="popover"
      (ionChange)="newSoundType($event, ionSelect)"
    >
```

Then in the function I send the event but also reset the value of `ionSelect`

```
public emitNewSoundType(event: CustomEvent<IonSelect>, element: IonSelect): void {
    if (this.trainingConfig) {
      element.value = this.configObject.soundType;
    }
    this.newSoundType.emit(event);
  }
```

stackblitz with an example (using ionic3 because I could not bring ionic 4 to work with stackblitz) https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-select-problem-solution?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Answer (score 2):

You can force ion-select to display the value of configObject by using the [selectedText property](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#properties).

In your example HTML:

```
<ion-select
      [ngModel]="configObject.soundType"
      [selectedText]="configObject.soundType"
      interface="popover"
      (ionChange)="newSoundType($event)"
    >
```

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-select-problem-5tukpn)

Comment: I spoke too early, even though the value does not change externally inside the popover the value is still `SoundTypeC`: https://imgur.com/a/7prEatg

Answer (score 0):

`objectConfig` still holds the old value as you have not set Two way binding i.e.`[(value)]="objectConfig!.soundType"`.

Comment: I know, and that is what I need/want. The old value is the **correct** value. `ion-select` is the one who is holding a wrong one.

Comment: hi yes i believe once you do the 2 way binding your issue should resolve. if not create a plunkr solution so we can help to debug.

Comment: No, I had the banana in the box but the problem was the same. I am already trying to make a plunkr or stackblitz unsuccessfully :( I can not bring ionic to work

Comment: I have added a stackblitz with the problem @chirag-patel

Comment: @distante its just a blank app, please add some code to show your error.

Comment: The code is inside the `home.ts` file I have update the link to open it automatically.

Comment: @distante thanks working now. I cant re-produce the issue however; 1- no cancel option as you have set the `interface="popover"` 2 - after removing the interface option, it works fine; i can change the option click 'cancel' and it stays as the original

Comment: Yes, it needs to be a pop over interface. The app has all their select in this way.

Comment: well I do not see the issue reproducing in the stackblitz example then, am i missing something?

Comment: See the answer from @carlosGlegaspi

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-select
   [value]="order.order_status"
   [interface]="'popover'"
   (ionChange)="onStatusChange($event)"
>
```

...

```
onStatusChange($event) {

   ...your condition here...

   ...cancel like this...
   const temp = this.order.order_status;
   this.order.order_status = null;
   setTimeout( () => {
       this.order.order_status = temp;
   }, 200);
```

Hacky but it works.

Ionic4